# How to add Tailwind CSS to Rails without Webpacker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

I'd like to run Tailwind CSS in my Rails 6 application. I've chosen to keep sprockets and not use Webpacker. I've attempted to install Tailwind with Yarn without any success, but my experience is also limited.

How do I approach this?

Comment: Is CDN an option? =)

Comment: @BenjaminBeganović - No, sadly not. When using CDN I can't modify the theme or use variants etc. The magic is ruined.

Comment: Take a look at my answer =)

Answer (score 1):

Adam Wathan, creator of Tailwind did the amazing cast on how to set up it and it does not involve Webpack.
https://tailwindcss.com/course/setting-up-tailwind-and-postcss/

Comment: Hiding in plain sight. Thanks a lot - I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: Everything works except @apply. They don't get compiled. So they get served directly to the browser, which throws a "Unknown property name" at it in dev tools.